# RingCentral API User Contact Endpont Authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, ringcentral

I'm trying to create a server-only (no UI) application with the RingCentral API. The goal is to use their new address book endpoint to automatically create/update the user contacts for all extensions in our company.

This seems like it should be straightforward and shouldn't require user authentication (since it's a private application), but I can't see from the docs how I can authorize such an API call. The auth options seem to all require the user to provide explicit authorization. Is there some way to do what I'm trying to do with just the client access id and secret provided by RC?

Answer (score 0):

The RingCentral API still requires OAuth 2.0 user authorization for server-only private applications because the authorized user is used to determine authorization scope. For example, a user with administrative privileges can access/modify resources on a company-wide level while an individual user may only be able to access/modify resources for their own user.

In your case, if you want to create a private app (private = for use only by your company), a simple way is to use the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant (username, extension, and password) in your code without requiring a UI (OAuth pop-up).

If you want this app to have administrative access you can use the credentials for a user extension with admin privileges. You can either use the existing admin extension or create a new one and assign admin privileges.

Comment: So you're saying I have to hard code the user name and password of an admin into my app to make this simple call work? That seems like a horrible implementation.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying that and that is not how this is typically deployed. There should be no username / password credentials in your code. One popular way to do this is to place the credentials in the environment, such as a `dotenv` file or other source. A JS implementation is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv but this is done in multiple languages. Of course, file access to your dotenv file should be locked down.

Comment: Of note, RingCentral tutorials use `dotenv` files and here are two examples: https://github.com/ringcentral-tutorials/data-archival-php-demo , https://github.com/ringcentral-tutorials/botkit-watson-bot-nodejs-demo